# well formed String as output of decryption using wrong key, AES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm searching a known encryption algorithm that would let me encrypt data with a key and if the data is decrypted with another key would give me data that is different from  the first one. It's string data. I tried AES but the problem is that the result of decryption using a wrong key gives a lot of invalid symbols so the resulting String is differentiable from a result given with a good key.

Is there a work around to this?

I did this so far:

```
private static final String truc = "f41a3ff27aab7d5c";


public static String encryptPass(String pass,String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        BCrypt bcrypt = new BCrypt();
        SecretKey keyL =  new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES");

        Cipher AesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        AesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyL, new IvParameterSpec(truc.getBytes()));
        byte[] encVal = AesCipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
        pass = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.i("ADA", "encoded pass: " + pass);

        return pass;
    }

    public static String decryptPass(String encPass , String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        SecretKey keyL =  new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES");
        Cipher AesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        AesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyL, new IvParameterSpec(truc.getBytes()));
        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(encPass, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decValue = AesCipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        Log.i("ADA", "decrpyted pass: " + decryptedValue);

        return decryptedValue;
    }
```

After reading [the answer of MaybeWeCouldStartAVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596994/aes-badpaddingexception), last paragraph I used "AES/CTR/NoPadding".

When I'm saying a well formed String I'm expecting mostly ASCII chars 32 to 125.

Is there something out there that would respond to my needs, or should I just roll my own encryption algorithm (I heard it's not advised but if it's my only option well..)?

I'm not trying to restrict access to any data. Data is fully visible by anyone who would use the app but unless they have the right key they should see erroneous data (that don't obviously look erroneous). 
The idea is to restrain brute force.

Comment: If you are not an expert in this area and not part of a group of experts in this area, you should never consider "creating" your own encryption algorithm. http://www.imobilesitter.com/index_en.php is something that sounds like what you want to accomplish. Behind this is a big research institution, they know what they are doing. The only simple thing I could come up with is that you transform every "invalid" symbol to a valid one still using AES. So if the right key is used, the correct string appears; if the wrong key is used some valid looking string appears. However, padding cannot be used.

Comment: @fhissen Thanks for the answer. However, correct me if I'm wrong but if the key is the same length of the data I'm trying to protect (or even bigger) then it's pretty easy to achieve even by using old algorithm like the running key cipher it's like you have no data at all

Comment: Use what you have, and before sending back the result, replace every character that is not in your accepted range by a character that is.

Comment: @JBNizet  Yeah I thought about this already. The problem I see is how I determine which char the wrong char is replaced with. I could randomize it. The problem about this (and this is way beyond the scope of what I know) is that maybe there is a way to determine if a char has been randomized or not. First thing that pops to my mind is that additional computation has to be done thus the time it takes to compute the decrypted data is not the same if the key is a wrong one or a good one. Thus allowing brute force. I could make the method takes  constant time but I'm afraid there is smtg else.

Comment: If you think of it as a "gimmick" of an app, e.g., from the user perspective there will always be something readable no matter which key is used, then this does not matter. If you talk about cryptoanalysis, the "character replacing" idea has no effect at all since an attacker would attack the algorithm before that.

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer here. You could ask a non-code question on [crypto.se] maybe with a focus on format-preserving encryption. If you get an answer there, you could do your research and ask a better question here.

Comment: Talking about the running key cipher, the essential question would be how do you generate the key(s)? Wikipedia has some notes on the security of the rkc (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Running_key_cipher&oldid=652921685#Security) to give you an idea. This would only be secure if you can generate a real One-Time-Pad! There are many aspects to consider...

Comment: @fhissen Thanks for the reply. You said "an attacker would attack the algorithm before that". My understanding is that if the data is about the same size of the key and the key is irretrievable then there is no way of attacking the algorithm ie it's like there is no data at all. Even with a Caesar type algo where I'd shift letters thanks to a key ("abc" w/ "cbc" = "ddf") if I don't have the key there is no way of finding data. The problem though is that I'll store a bunch of passwords of say 8 chars and the key for all those will be a key of say 10 chars(same key). So I guess this is a problem

Comment: @ced I was just referring to the (simple) idea of replacing invalid chars with valid chars. Regarding cryptoanalysis this would not enhance security (e.g., against brute force). It would just be a nice gimmick to users, like "here you can access my password app" but you would only see gibberish...

Comment: @ced: artjom-b is right, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ would be a good address to discuss this in detail...